# Getting Error Message When Building In TFS

Tags: tfs, gated-checkin

I am having an issue where virtually every Package during the nuget restore (when building on TFS agent) is being marked as not compatible.  Why would this be the case?  This builds perfectly on my local machine but will not work when in TFS.  It just doesn't make sense to me why the inclusion of AspNetCore.All version 2.1.0 wouldn't be compatible with netcoreapp2.1.  Is there some other version that I should be using in my solution or is something wrong with my agent?

```
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Ini 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Ini 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.KeyPerFile 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.KeyPerFile 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Composite 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Http 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Http 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Localization 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Localization 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.TraceSource 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.TraceSource 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc 2.1.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.0.0-beta4 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.0.0-beta4 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1.
```

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Agents\FirstStrikeCoreMaintenance_work\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_13261.config
Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Error: C:\Agents\FirstStrikeCoreMaintenance_work_tool\NuGet\4.0.0\x64\nuget.exe failed with return code: 1
Packages failed to restore

Answer (score 0):

Using the .net core build, publish, and restore task allowed the project to build successfully.  Using the Visual Studio Build would not work.